# I can not get run trigger on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have these tables on mySQL (I write all on command line)

```
TITOLO(isin varchar(12), maxAss int, minAss int, primary key(isin))

QUOTAZIONE(id int, min int, max int, date date, isin varchar(12), primary key(id), foreign key(isin) references TITOLO(isin))
```

Now i want to create a trigger that every time i insert a row in `QUOTAZIONE` it check if `min < minASS or max > maxAss` if it is true update the value on the table `TITOLO`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER AggiornaTitolo
AFTER INSERT ON quotazione
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE massimo int;
DECLARE minimo int;
SELECT maxAss, minAss INTO massimo, minimo FROM titolo WHERE titolo.isin = NEW.isin;
IF massimo > maxAss THEN
UPDATE titolo
SET maxAss = massimo;
IF minimo < minAss THEN
UPDATE titolo
SET minAss = minimo; 
END IF;
END;
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

but the console write `error 1064 (42000) at line 14.`
Can someone please help me?

Comment: So where is line 14?

Comment: You're missing one END IF. After the first UPDATE.

Comment: With proper indentations, you probably would have spotted the error.

Comment: @McAdam331 - I posted it as a wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`McAdams331` already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250120/i-can-not-get-run-trigger-on-mysql#comment50497684_31250120) you're missing the second `ENDIF`:

```
00000001 DELIMITER $$
00000002 CREATE TRIGGER AggiornaTitolo
00000003 AFTER INSERT ON quotazione
00000004 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
00000005    DECLARE massimo int;
00000006    DECLARE minimo int;
00000007    SELECT maxAss, minAss INTO massimo, minimo FROM titolo WHERE titolo.isin = NEW.isin;
00000008    IF massimo > maxAss THEN
00000009        UPDATE titolo
00000010        SET maxAss = massimo;
00000011        IF minimo < minAss THEN
00000012            UPDATE titolo
00000013            SET minAss = minimo; 
00000014        END IF;
<missing>   END IF;          
00000015 END;
00000016 $$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ok, now it is run. But my trigger could you give me a hand on the trigger as it does not do what it should do. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to create a new question, provide sample data, your actual result and the desired result.